# How can I marshal an X500Principal with JAXB?

Tags: jaxb, marshalling

The class `javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal` is final and (of course) not annotated with JAXB annotations? So how can I marshal it as part of a larger object graph? I would like to substitute it with the value of it's `name` property.

**Edit**

The solution is straightforward:

```
final class X500PrincipalXmlAdapter
extends XmlAdapter<String, X500Principal> {
    @Override public X500Principal unmarshal(String name) {
        return new X500Principal(name);
    }

    @Override public String marshal(X500Principal principal) {
        return principal.getName();
    }
}
```

Actually, I wonder why JAXB lets me get away with a non-public XMLAdapter class, but I certainly prefer it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `XmlAdapter` for this use case.  The `XmlAdapter` is used to convert an unmappable object into a mappable one.  The `XmlAdapter` is configured on a field/property using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation.